# Android parcelable readtypedlist out of memory error

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I have been trying to debug this out of memory error that's occurring in my parcelable object. 
I'm really stuck on this one. I checked the order and it seems correct to me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.intuch.interfaces.ListRow;

public class ProfileModel implements Parcelable{

    public String linkedinID;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;
    public String pictureURL;
    public String headline;
    public String industry;
    public String interests;

    public List<EducationModel> education = new ArrayList<EducationModel>();
    public List<PositionModel> position = new ArrayList<PositionModel>();

    public boolean introduceOthers;
    public boolean answerQuestions;
    public boolean beMentor;
    public boolean graduated;

    public ProfileModel () {
        education = new ArrayList<EducationModel>();
        position = new ArrayList<PositionModel>();
    }

    public ProfileModel (Parcel in) {
        this();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(linkedinID);
        dest.writeString(firstName);
        dest.writeString(lastName);
        dest.writeString(email);
        dest.writeString(pictureURL);
        dest.writeString(headline);
        dest.writeString(industry);
        dest.writeString(interests);

        dest.writeList(education);
        dest.writeList(position);

        boolean[] myBooleanArr = new boolean[4];
        myBooleanArr[0]=introduceOthers;
        myBooleanArr[1]=answerQuestions;
        myBooleanArr[2]=beMentor;
        myBooleanArr[3]=graduated;
        dest.writeBooleanArray(myBooleanArr);       
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ProfileModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ProfileModel>() {

          public ProfileModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
             return new ProfileModel(source);
          }

          public ProfileModel[] newArray(int size) {
             return new ProfileModel[size];
          }

       };

        /*
        * Constructor calls read to create object
        */
       private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
          this.linkedinID = in.readString();
          this.firstName = in.readString();
          this.lastName = in.readString();
          this.email = in.readString();
          this.pictureURL = in.readString();
          this.headline = in.readString();
          this.industry = in.readString();
          this.interests = in.readString();

          in.readTypedList(education, EducationModel.CREATOR); 
          in.readTypedList(position, PositionModel.CREATOR);

          boolean[] myBooleanArr = new boolean[4];
          in.readBooleanArray(myBooleanArr);

          introduceOthers=myBooleanArr[0];
          answerQuestions=myBooleanArr[1];
          beMentor=myBooleanArr[2];
          graduated=myBooleanArr[3];
       }

}
```

The error occurs in the following line:

```
in.readTypedList(position, PositionModel.CREATOR);
```

Here are my other classes:

EducationalModel:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class EducationModel implements Parcelable{
    public String degree;
    public String schoolName;
    public int graduated;

    private EducationModel(Parcel in) {
        degree = in.readString();
        schoolName = in.readString();
        graduated = in.readInt();
      } 

    public EducationModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(degree);
        dest.writeString(schoolName);
        dest.writeInt(graduated);
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<EducationModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<EducationModel>() {
        public EducationModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new EducationModel(in);
        }

        public EducationModel[] newArray(int size) {
         return new EducationModel[size];
        }
      };

}
```

PositionModel:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class PositionModel implements Parcelable{
    public String company;
    public String title;

    private PositionModel(Parcel in) {
        company = in.readString();
        title = in.readString();
      } 

    public PositionModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(company);
        dest.writeString(title);
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<PositionModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PositionModel>() {
        public PositionModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new PositionModel(in);
        }

        public PositionModel[] newArray(int size) {
         return new PositionModel[size];
        }
      };

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're writing the lists out using the generic `writeList` method but reading them back using `readTypedList` call.  These are not compatible.  Check the documentation for `readTypedList`:

```
The list must have previously been written via writeTypedList(List) with the same object type.
```

Using a typed list allows the `Parcel` to have more efficient memory usage as it doesn't write the type of each object in the list into the stream.  So if you try to read back list data as if it were written in "typed" but was instead written as a generic list, the parcel processing is getting unexpected data and causing it to throw up.

Comment: Wow!!!, my app was failing with OOM using over 100MB of memory because I was writing a List of Strings with WriteList() and reading back with readStringList. Now it uses <5MB of memory. you saved my day Larry @Larry Schiefer

Comment: Glad you found the info helpful!